# Improper use of system() call?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, ffmpeg

I have a particle system program that generates a `.dat` file with particle coordinates in every iteration. The end goal is to run the program multiple times via a script with different parameters. So, I am trying to setup my program in a way that, for every run, all relevant data are going to be stored in a folder.

What I do is to generate `PNGs` from the `.dat` files with `Gnuplot`, call `ffmpeg` to create a video out of the `PNGs`, use `WinRAR` to compress the `.dat` files and finally clean up, by deleting all the intermediate files. This works, when I do it in the working directory.

Now I try to create a new directory and do the same stuff in there. My code:

```
// Load the proper library to use chdir() function
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <direct.h>
#elif defined __linux__ || defined __APPLE__&&__MACH__
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

// Make output directory and change working directory to new directory
    ostringstream dirCommand;
    dirCommand << "mkdir " << folderName_str;
    system(dirCommand.str().c_str());
    const char* test  = folderName_str.c_str();
    #ifdef _WIN32
        if(_chdir(test))
        {
            printf( "Unable to locate the directory: %s\n",test);
            return;
        }
    #elif defined __linux__ || defined __APPLE__&&__MACH__
        if(chdir(test))
        {
            printf( "Unable to locate the directory: %s\n",test);
            return;
        }
    #endif
        else
            printf("Created output directory...\n");
```

Already for this part, I know that there are going to be objections. I have looked extensively on SO and many people favor `SetCurrentDirectory()` for Windows, or they are skeptical about using `system()`. In my defense, I am a novice programmer and my knowledge is really limited...

Now, when I try to make the video with `FFMpeg` and then rar/tar my files:

```
// Make video
        std::cout << "Generating Video..." << endl;
        ostringstream command;
        command << "ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/0.1 -i output_%01d.png -vcodec mpeg4 " << videoName_str << ".avi -loglevel quiet";
        std::system(command.str().c_str());

        // Clean Up!
        std::cout << "Cleaning up!" << endl;
        ostringstream command2;
        #ifdef _WIN32
            command2 << "rar -inul a " << videoName_str << ".rar *.dat settings.gp loadfile.gp";
        #elif defined __linux__ || defined __APPLE__&&__MACH__
            command2 << "tar cf " << videoName_str << ".tar *.dat settings.gp loadfile.gp";
        #endif
        std::system(command2.str().c_str());
```

I get very different behaviors in Win/ Linux.

## Win 7 x64, Visual Studio 2010/12

In windows, the folder is created. The `.dat` files are generated correctly and `gnuplot` plots the `PNGs` as well. When `ffmpeg` is called, nothing happens. No error message from `FFMpeg` or anything. The same goes for `WinRAR`. Maybe, for the last thing, I can use the command line utility of `7z` which is free!

## Linux Mint 14 x64, Qt 4.8.1

Strangely enough, the behavior is inverted from that of Windows. As soon as the dir is changed, only the first `.dat` file is generated. It is as if every subsequent call I make to `fprintf()` for my file generation does not work, or gets lost somewhere. `Gnuplot` works, as do `ffmpeg` and `tar`!!

I am really perplexed. Any help, would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think you'd be better off just writing shell scripts to do this.  You might need a separate one for each platform, but who cares--the conditional compilation you've got now amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! I was really obsessing over this. But the message to take home is to learn how to manage my errors. I must predict invalid user input better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points that might be helpful:

1. Make sure to check the result of every system call, including system() and fprintf().
2. It's been a while since I last touched Windows; I remember that depending on how binaries were linked, they would not always print out to the same console. So ffmpeg/winrar could be throwing the error messages away, or just allocating a new, short-lived console to print.
3. I would use mkdir/_mkdir instead of calling system().
4. With popen()/_popen() you can get more control over the error output.
5. Consider using a shell script or bat file.

Comment: I guess easier is better! I will look into making a script out of this. I will keep your helpful tips in mind. I need to learn error control!!